# How to write Multiple if-else statement using Java 8 Stream API?

Tags: java-8

I just want implement multiple if else condition or Below given code in Stream API of java 8.

Greatest Common Divisor Code using recursion Logic -:

```
if(a == b)
            return a;
        if(a%b == 0)
            return b;
        if(b%a == 0)
            return a;
        if(a>b)
            return (gcd(a%b,b));
        else
            return(gcd(a,b%a));

// gcd (int a,int b) is a function
```

Comment: Seems like you'll only ever have one value and there will always be a value (i.e. all inputs are valid). What does that have to do with streams?

Comment: Actually gcd() method accept two parameter and rest logic works on that.

Comment: If-else statements without curly braces .... [not recommended!](https://dzone.com/articles/omitting-braces-not-just-a-mat). More on topic, why would you want to do this with streams?

Comment: @RobinTopper Always having curly braces made more sense before people had code formatters in their IDE.

Comment: The state of each recursion or iteration depends on the previous one. You could use Streams, but the code is much clearer without it. i.e. this is not a good example for using a Stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams are not a good choice for replacing recursion or iteration where the state of each iteration depends on the previous one.  You can use Streams, but as you can see, it's pretty horrible.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int[][] pair = {{a, b}};
    return IntStream.of(
            IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a, b))
                    .mapToObj(i -> pair[0] = (pair[0][0] > pair[0][1]
                            ? new int[]{pair[0][0] % pair[0][1], pair[0][1]}
                            : new int[]{pair[0][0], pair[0][1] % pair[0][0]}))
                    .filter(p -> p[0] == 0 || p[1] == 0)
                    .findAny().orElse(new int[2]))
            .max()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: 1+ for the horrible horrible example